# How do I highlight an entire trace upon hover in Plotly for Python?

Tags: python, plotly

I want a trace to be highlighted (color or opacity change) when selected with mouse hover.  I have looked into `restyle` functionality, but it may not be appropriate for my use case.

[image]

It looks like [this has been discussed on Github](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1847), but I'm not sure if it has been resolved/implemented.

Here is an example in Bokeh of what I want to accomplish in Plotly Python:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
output_notebook()

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400,y_range=(0.2,0.5))


y_vals = [0.22,0.22,0.25,0.25,0.26,0.26,0.27,0.27]
y_vals2 = [y*1.4 for y in y_vals]
x_vals = [0,1,1,2,2,2,2,3]
data_dict = {'x':[x_vals,x_vals],
             'y':[y_vals,y_vals2],
             'color':["firebrick", "navy"],
             'alpha':[0.1, 0.1]}

source = ColumnDataSource(data_dict)

p.multi_line('x','y',source=source,
             color='color', alpha='alpha', line_width=4,
             hover_line_alpha=1.0,hover_line_color='color')

p.add_tools(HoverTool(show_arrow=True,
                      line_policy='nearest',
                      ))
show(p)
```

[image: hover above top line]
[image: hover above bottom line]

Comment: Are you trying to use it an IPython notebook or using Dash?

Comment: Jupyter notebook or lab

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use Plotly's `FigureWidget` functionality.
[image]

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import random

f = go.FigureWidget()
f.layout.hovermode = 'closest'
f.layout.hoverdistance = -1 #ensures no "gaps" for selecting sparse data
default_linewidth = 2
highlighted_linewidth_delta = 2

# just some traces with random data points  
num_of_traces = 5
random.seed = 42
for i in range(num_of_traces):
    y = [random.random() + i / 2 for _ in range(100)]
    trace = go.Scatter(y=y, mode='lines', line={ 'width': default_linewidth })
    f.add_trace(trace)

# our custom event handler
def update_trace(trace, points, selector):
    # this list stores the points which were clicked on
    # in all but one trace they are empty
    if len(points.point_inds) == 0:
        return
        
    for i,_ in enumerate(f.data):
        f.data[i]['line']['width'] = default_linewidth + highlighted_linewidth_delta * (i == points.trace_index)


# we need to add the on_click event to each trace separately       
for i in range( len(f.data) ):
    f.data[i].on_click(update_trace)

# let's show the figure 
f
```

Comment: In jupyter lab, f is not rendered, but instead only returns some text.

Comment: @IvoMerchiers: Are other Plotly figures shown correctly in your environment?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, copied your code above and the figure won't render unless I change f to f.show(),  albeit even then the on_click event does not work. Running Jupyter Notebook, any idea on what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: @MSalty hm, it's still working with latest Plotly version (4.10.0) on Windows inside a Python3.7 Jupyter Notebook. Sometimes it took Plotly some time to "warm up" until the clicks were recognized. Perhaps you can post your code and setup as new question?

Comment: I ended up solving the problem and updated my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63885102/change-color-of-an-entire-trace-on-hover-click-in-plotly/63902598#63902598 an extension had not been enabled in conda.

Comment: using conda, python 3.7, and jupyter notebook in vscode, this works

Comment: how to change the code for a IDE (like pycharm)?