# Plotly in Python: how to highlight a trace on hover?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization

I have the following figure definition:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3], y=[1,2,3], name="A"))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3], y=[1,3,5], name="B"))
fig.show()
```

[image]

I would like to highlight a trace upon **hover**, which would reduce the opacity of all other traces and make the selected one bold preferably.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I highlight an entire trace upon hover in Plotly for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53327572/how-do-i-highlight-an-entire-trace-upon-hover-in-plotly-for-python)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [vestland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3437787/vestland), I think I managed to get it working by following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53327572/how-do-i-highlight-an-entire-trace-upon-hover-in-plotly-for-python). I had to change `go.Figure` to `go.FigureWidget` and I also had to add a `update_trace` method that appears in the provided link. Then I changed `on_click` callback to `on_hover` and it worked. The solution isn't ideal, I don't really like the fact that we need to loop over each data point and I don't like that the `update_trace` function relies on `go.FigureWidget` object from outer scope, so if anyone has a cleaner way to solve this, please let us know.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your code to the above? I don't seem to be able to get the colour to update on my plotly graph and looking to achieve this exact functionality

Comment: To be honest, I ended up not using the solution proposed in my own answer. I ended up updating figure attributes like opacity and colour on callback and then resetting then immediately after.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up solving mine too (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63885102/change-color-of-an-entire-trace-on-hover-click-in-plotly/63902598#63902598), would love a new method which doesn't involve looping over each trace to eventuate.

Comment: @IVR care to show your solution?

Comment: @MSalty does your solution only works for Jupyter?

Comment: @KansaiRobot I was only using this in Jupyter sorry, so I'm unable to answer if it works in other environments