# Dash: implementing a trace highlight callback

Tags: javascript, python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-dash

I have a basic dash application with the following `app.py` file:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def generate_plot():
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[1, 2, 3], name="A", line={"width": 1}))
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[1, 3, 5], name="B", line={"width": 1}))
    return fig

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children="title", className="title"),
    dcc.Graph(figure=generate_plot(), className="plot")
])
```

I would like to highlight (increase line width to 5) a trace upon hover. So far I have found a way to achieve this in a Jupyter notebook by using `go.FigureWidget` object instead of `go.Figure` (see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53327572/how-do-i-highlight-an-entire-trace-upon-hover-in-plotly-for-python) for more info), however, it doesn't work in Dash. If anyone has any ideas on how to achieve the desired effect, please let us know.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I managed to resolve half of the problem.

First, if you are using a method to generate your figure, you need to save it into a separate object:

```
my_plot = generate_plot()
```

Second, you need to give your figure an ID:

```
dcc.Graph(figure=my_plot, id="my_plot")
```

Third, you need to add an `app.callback` like this:

```
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output("my_plot", "figure"),
    [dash.dependencies.Input("my_plot", "hoverData")]
)
def highlight_trace(hover_data):
    # here you set the default settings
    for trace in my_pot.data:
        country["line"]["width"] = 1
        country["opacity"] = 0.5
    if hover_data:
        trace_index = hover_data["points"][0]["curveNumber"]
        my_plot.data[trace_index]["line"]["width"] = 5
        my_plot.data[trace_index]["opacity"] = 1
    return my_plot
```

This will highlight the trace on hover but it will only reset its state when you hover over another trace (which may be the intended behaviour in some cases). I still haven't figured out how to reset the trace appearance as soon as you are not hovering over it, **so if you have any suggestions about that, please let us know, until then I'll consider this question unanswered**

**EDIT**

Ok, I figured out how to reset hover effects: just add `clear_on_hover` parameter like this: `dcc.Graph(figure=my_plot, id="my_plot", clear_on_hover=True)`

Many thanks