# plotly (python,) implement hovermode in linechart (not with jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, plotly, hover

I try to implement the hovermode in plotly (pyhton) to highlight lines, like this example:
[How do I highlight an entire trace upon hover in Plotly for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53327572/how-do-i-highlight-an-entire-trace-upon-hover-in-plotly-for-python)

But I do not use jupyter notebook (i use pycharm), so the solution with 'FigureWidget' does not work for my problem. I also use px.line (plotly.express) instead of go.Scatter (plotly.graph_objs). But I also welcome a solution with go.Scatter.

```
import plotly.express as px

# data
df = px.data.gapminder()
df = df[df['country'].isin(['Canada', 'USA', 'Norway', 'Sweden', 'Germany'])]

# plotly
fig = px.line(df, x='year', y='lifeExp',
              color='country')

fig.update_traces(patch={"line": {"color": "grey", "width": 4}})

fig.show()
```

Comment: This can be achieved with JavaScript, but it needs great time and effort to be done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  sounds complicated and I have no experience in JavaScript. This means that in python is no solution?

Comment: You should wait, there maybe someone who has a solution. I answered based on my best knowledge.

Comment: I want to ask: you want to highlight the line you hover, and all other lines should be in grey color or just highlight the hovered line and keep the other's colors unchanged?

Comment: i would prefer the first solution, the second would be better than nothing

Comment: But the link you referred to in your question is the second option.

Comment: Look at this link https://codepen.io/etpinard/pen/RQQqzq?editors=0010